# How to unmarshal JSON with a generic interface as a field

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I have a generic Response object with the following struct:

```golang
type Response struct {
    Data          Data   `json:"data"`
    Error         string `json:"error,omitempty"`
    NextPageToken string `json:"next_page_token,omitempty"`
}
```

The `Data` type is an interface, with many implementations (think PingResponse, etc). How do I unmarshal the `Response` into its underlying type? The full example is below, which always triggers the error `error: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field Response.data of type main.Data`
:

```golang
type Response struct {
    Data          Data   `json:"data"`
    Error         string `json:"error,omitempty"`
    NextPageToken string `json:"next_page_token,omitempty"`
}

type Data interface{
    Foo()
}

type TypeA struct {
    Field1 string `json:"field1"`
    Field2 int    `json:"field2"`
}

func (a *TypeA) Foo() {}

type TypeB struct {
    Field3 float64 `json:"field3"`
}

func (b *TypeB) Foo() {}

func main() {
    jsonStr := `{
        "data": {
            "field1": "some string",
            "field2": 123
        },
        "error": "",
        "next_page_token": ""
    }`

    var response Response
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonStr), &response)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
        return
    }

    switch data := response.Data.(type) {
    case *TypeA:
        fmt.Println("TypeA:", data.Field1, data.Field2)
    case *TypeB:
        fmt.Println("TypeB:", data.Field3)
    default:
        fmt.Println("Unknown type")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to tell `encoding/json` which concrete type to unmarshal to. The package can not do it for you.

Let's assume that `TypeA` and `TypeB` are defined as:

```
type TypeA struct {
    FieldA string `json:"field"`
}

type TypeB struct {
    FieldB string `json:"field"`
}
```

There is no way to decide which type to unmarshal to in this case.

Regarding your example, we can tell `encoding/json` which type to unmarshal to like this:

```
- var response Response
+ response := Response{Data: &TypeA{}}
```

If you don't know the type beforehand, you can marshal it into `map[string]interface{}`:

```
 type Response struct {
-   Data          Data                   `json:"data"`
+   Data          map[string]interface{} `json:"data"`
    Error         string                 `json:"error,omitempty"` 
    NextPageToken string                 `json:"next_page_token,omitempty"`
 }
```

And determine the type like this:

```golang
if field1, ok := response.Data["field1"]; ok {
    fmt.Println("TypeA:", field1, response.Data["field2"])
} else {
    if field3, ok := response.Data["field3"]; ok {
        fmt.Println("TypeB:", field3)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Unknown type")
    }
}
```

Another solution is to embed the type information in the json:

```
 jsonStr := `{
     "data": {
         "field1": "some string",
         "field2": 123
     },
+    type": "A",
     "error": "",
     "next_page_token": ""
 }`

 type Response struct {
-   Data          Data            `json:"data"`
+   Data          json.RawMessage `json:"data"`
+   Type          string          `json:"type"`
    Error         string          `json:"error,omitempty"`
    NextPageToken string          `json:"next_page_token,omitempty"`
 }
```

And then decode `response.Data` according to the value of `response.Type`. See the example provided by `encoding/json`: https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#example-RawMessage-Unmarshal.

Comment: if you have to inspect the data to determine how to cast it properly, you might find https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure useful